# Create a routes entry from your own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm writing a gem and I'm going to use it with Rails 4. Is it possible for me to add a route from my Gem rather than from config/routes.rb in my rails project? I want this to be inside a gem so I can include it in more than one Rails project without having to configure every Rails project, rather do it once in the gem. Is that possible and how?

i.e :

If my routes were :

```
get 'test' => 'users#test'
```

how would that translate into my gem. If my gem were used as an engine just like RB suggested in his answer :

```
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    get 'test' => 'users#test'
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the Engine Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes) of Ruby on Rails. Basically you'll want to create the file in config/routes.rb (on your gem folder) and add the following:

```
YourGemName::Engine.routes.draw do
  get 'test' => 'users#test'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible if you make your gem an engine.

Read the [Getting Started with Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) guide.